# NGINX trailing slash but exclude wp-json and wp-admin

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I'm using this NGINX rule to force trailing slashes for a WordPress site:

```
rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
```

But this rule is making some trouble with Gutenberg and wp-json.

How can I use the rule above for everything excepting /wp-json/* and /wp-admin/* ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the negative regex lookahead:

```
rewrite ^(?!/wp-admin|/wp-json)([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
```

See [this](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) article for explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use what you have in your question. This should do the trick and is the code I use for the same.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/wp-json/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301,NE]
```